# catch editing-Mode left and change label from UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone

i have a little problem. when i enter the edit mode of my uitableview the a manuel added label should disappear. i realized this by setting the alpha of this label-field to 0 in following method:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if ([self isEditing] && [indexPath row] == [tripArray count]) {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert;
    }
    [[[[self tableView] cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] detailTextLabel] setAlpha:0];
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;

}
```

But in which delegate-methode of my tableview i can set the alpha back to 1, when the edit mode was finished???
hopefully someone has an idea? i didn't find the right one......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a work around and used the standard text labels from the standard cells. this text labels disappear in edit mode... not a nice way, but it did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: [`tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006941-CH3-SW11). `UITableView` will call this data source method when the user taps on the delete or insert button on a table view cell.

Comment: but what is when the user pushes just the 'done'-button and no row is deleted or inserted?